# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present (Ember JS)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, content-security-policy

I am working on an ember app ( Ember 2.11.0 ). Here is my content security policy settings:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': "'self'",
  'font-src': "'self'",
  'connect-src': "'self' 'localhost:4200' 'some-url'",
  'img-src': "'self'",
  'style-src': "'self' *",
  'media-src': "'self'"
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to make the following XMLHttpRequest:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load **url-to-sccess**. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any suggestions?

Comment: your server resource (the remote server you are calling) needs to allow the `localhost:4200` origin in its CORS implementation

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/